# Como usar os argumentos passados para um script python?

Tags: python

Em `scripts` php, podemos, quando executamos pela linha de comandos, capturar os seus valores dos argumentos passados através da variável `$argv` e o seu número através da variável `$argc`.

Por exemplo (Script):

```
echo 'My name is ', $argv[1]
```

Exemplo chamada:

```
 my_name_is.php Wallace
```

A saída será:

> My name is Wallace

E no `Python`? Existe alguma maneira de capturar os argumentos passados para um script, via linha de comando?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1009879/1518921), você pode importar a biblioteca `sys`, alguns exemplos:

```
import sys

print "\n".join(sys.argv)
```

Outro exemplo com `sys`

```
import sys

for value in sys.argv:
    print value
```

Geralmente, o primeiro argumento de `argv` sempre é o nome do script que está sendo executado.

Por exemplo:

```
 > args.py one two tree
```

Retornaria

```
['args.py', 'one', 'two', 'tree']
```

Se você quiser retornar do argumento `1` em diante (listas começam a contagem do 0 `zero`), pode usar o `slice` para cortar o primeiro elemento da lista de argumentos.

Assim:

```
print sys.argv[1:]
```

Retorno:

```
['one', 'two', 'tree']
```

Se ainda você quiser usar a variável `argv` sem a necessidade de invocá-la do módulo `sys`, você pode fazer assim:

```
from sys import argv

print argv[1:]
```

Sei que tem outras maneiras de fazer, assim como o *Python* tem diferentes bibliotecas para propósitos semelhante, com o tempo vou editar e adicionar mais, acredito que o exemplo ficaria assim:

```
import sys

print 'Meu nome é ', sys.argv[1]
```